# Dagger NullPointerException 3rd class depending on 2nd class

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

In a project that is an Activity Model, Presenter and Model, the Activity Theme and Presenter and Presenter Model. When I do @Inject in Presenter to instantiate the Model it is never instantiated.

Do you need a dependency "cascade"?

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: fipedaggerrxjava, PID: 22258
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   fipedaggerrxjava.mvp.SelectMarcaContractMVP$Model.getMarcas(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference at
>   fipedaggerrxjava.module.marca.MarcaPresenter.initData(MarcaPresenter.java:35)
>   at
>   fipedaggerrxjava.module.marca.MarcaActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(MarcaActivity.java:63)

I already checked in Debug and really the Model that is not being instantiated by Dagger but I can not understand why.

**App**

```
public class App extends Application implements HasActivityInjector{

    @Inject
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().build().inject(App.this);
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

**ActivityBuilder**

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ActivityKey(MarcaActivity.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity> bindMarcaActivity (MarcaComponent.Builder builder);

}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Component(modules = {ActivityBuilder.class, AndroidInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(App app);

}
```

**AppModule**

```
@Module(subcomponents = MarcaComponent.class)
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("URL_MARCA")
    String provideStringURLBase(){
        return "https://fipe.parallelum.com.br/api/v1/";
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext(App app){
        return app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGsonRepositorie(){
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .create();
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpCliente1(){
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    RxJavaCallAdapterFactory provideRxJavaCallAdapterFactory(){
        return RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create();
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, Gson gson, RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxAdapter, @Named("URL_MARCA") String stringBaseURL){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(stringBaseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**MarcaComponent**

```
@Subcomponent(modules = MarcaModule.class)
@PerMarca
public interface MarcaComponent extends AndroidInjector<MarcaActivity>{

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MarcaActivity> {}

}
```

**MarcaModule**

```
@Module
public class MarcaModule{


    @Provides
    @PerMarca
    APIFIPE provideAPIFIPE(Retrofit retrofit){
        return retrofit.create(APIFIPE.class);
    }


    @Provides
    @PerMarca
    View provideViewMarca(MarcaActivity activity){
        return activity;
    }


    @Provides
    @PerMarca
    Presenter providePresenterMarca(){
        return new MarcaPresenter();
    }


    @Provides
    @PerMarca
    Model provideModelMarca(){
        return new MarcaModel();
    }


}
```

**AdapterMarca**

```
public class AdapterMarca extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Marca> mListMarca;

@Inject
public Context mContext;

public AdapterMarca(List<Marca> listMarca){
    this.mListMarca = listMarca;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListMarca.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mListMarca.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);

    TextView tvNome = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_marca);
    tvNome.setText(mListMarca.get(position).getName().toString());

    return view;
}


public void addListMarca(List<Marca> marcaList){
    mListMarca.clear();
    mListMarca.addAll(marcaList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

**MarcaActivity**

```
public class MarcaActivity extends BaseActivity implements HasActivityInjector, View {

    private RadioGroup radioGroupMarca;
    private String tipoSelect = "";

    private List<Marca> mListMarca;
    private AdapterMarca mAdapterMarca;

    private ListView listViewMarca;


    @Inject
    public Presenter mMarcaPresenter;

    @Inject
    protected DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(MarcaActivity.this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listViewMarca = findViewById(R.id.lv_marca);


        radioGroupMarca = findViewById(R.id.rg_tipo);

        radioGroupMarca.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int id = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                switch (id){
                    case R.id.rb_carros : tipoSelect = "carros";
                        mMarcaPresenter.initData(tipoSelect);
                        break;

                    case R.id.rb_motos : tipoSelect = "motos";
                        mMarcaPresenter.initData(tipoSelect);
                        break;

                    case R.id.rb_caminhoes : tipoSelect = "caminhoes";
                        mMarcaPresenter.initData(tipoSelect);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });



    }



    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }



    @Override
    public void onMarcaLoader(List<Marca> listMarcas) {
        if(mListMarca==null && listMarcas!=null){
            initListView();
        }

        if(mAdapterMarca!=null){
            mListMarca.clear();
            mListMarca = listMarcas;

            mAdapterMarca.addListMarca(mListMarca);
        }

    }


    private void initListView(){
        mAdapterMarca = new AdapterMarca(mListMarca);
        listViewMarca.setAdapter(mAdapterMarca);
    }

}
```

**MarcaPresenter**

```
@PerMarca
public class MarcaPresenter implements Presenter {

    @Inject
    View mMarcaView;


    @Inject
    Model mMarcaModel;

    @Inject
    public MarcaPresenter(){

    }


    @Override
    public void initData(String tipoMarca) {
        mMarcaModel.getMarcas(tipoMarca);
    }

    @Override
    public void getMarcas(List<Marca> listMarcas) {
        mMarcaView.onMarcaLoader(listMarcas);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowDialog(String title, String msg) {
        mMarcaView.onShowDialog(title, msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideShowDialog() {
        mMarcaView.onHideShowDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowToast(String s) {
        mMarcaView.onShowToast(s);
    }
}
```

**MarcaModel**

```
@PerMarca
public class MarcaModel implements Model {

    @Inject
    APIFIPE mApiFIPE;

    @Inject
    Presenter mMarcaPresenter;


    @Inject
    public MarcaModel(){

    }

    @Override
    public void getMarcas(String tipoVeiculo) {
        final List<Marca> marcaList = new ArrayList<>();
        Observable<List<Marca>> observable = mApiFIPE.getRepositories(tipoVeiculo);
        observable.subscribe(new Observer<List<Marca>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                mMarcaPresenter.getMarcas(marcaList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                mMarcaPresenter.onShowDialog("Erro", "Falha ao carregar lista de marcas");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Marca> marcas) {
                marcaList.addAll(marcas);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In below lines:

```
 public void onCompleted() {
     mMarcaPresenter.getMarcas(marcaList);
 }
```

-You trying to use mMarcePResenter and you inject it but you still need to use the App's component get assigned to mMarcaPresenter.

Initialize the injected value in below constructor:

```
    @Inject
    public MarcaModel(){
        mMarcaPresenter = 
    }
```

Comment: That's what I do not understand, because I need to pass this on to the Model constructor if I'm providing all of this in Dagger.
It was not just getting into the Model or Presenter or wherever I wanted and doing @Inject and ploft, was everything alright?

:)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared provider methods(in MarcaModule) for your model and presenter classes. Dagger uses those provider methods, ending up not supplying the field injected values.

Therefore, you need to supply your dependencies in your module(s), i.e. via Model and Presenter constructors.

**MarcaModel**

```
...
Presenter mMarcaPresenter;


@Inject
public MarcaModel(Presenter presenter){
    mMarcaPresenter = presenter
}
...
```

**MarcaModule**

```
@Module
public class MarcaModule{
    ...

    @Provides
    @PerMarca
    Model provideModelMarca(Presenter presenter){
        return new MarcaModel(presenter);
    }

}
```

Reading Dagger user's guide carefully might help you even more;

https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide